# Problems performing clearcase operation

Tags: clearcase

I am not able to add Connectors VOB to my load rules. Getting this CCRC Error when loading connectors.

getting error like :

> Clearcase CM Server :Error :Unable to determine version for VOB root
> directory
>
> Clearcase CM Server :Error :Unable to access
> "\Connectors":No such file or directory.
>
> Clearcase CM Server:Error :1 config spec load rule problems
> encountered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot access that folder because:

- either `\Connector` is not a vob tag
- or that vob tag is never selected by the selection rules of the snapshot view config spec (for instance, there would not be any `element * /main/LATEST`)